# What is meant by MSPS in this context?

Tags: dac

[This](http://www.entegra.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/X5-400M_datasheet.pdf) board has a DAC specified with 500MSPS.

Does that mean it can output 500 million voltage samples per second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. MSPS in Mega Samples Per Second.

So the DAC output voltage can change 500 million times per second.